# Why do I only get first 2 rows on this query when there are 5

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using this query on mysql:

```
 SELECT
    `sitio`.`id_unico_sitio` AS 'ID Unico', 
    `sitio`.`nombre` AS 'Nombre', 
    `departamentos`.`departamento` AS 'Departamento', 
    `municipios`.`municipio` AS 'Municipio', 
    `sitio`.`direccion` AS 'Direccion', 
    `sitio`.`coor_x` AS 'Latitud', 
    `sitio`.`coor_y` AS 'Longitud', 
    `operador`.`nombre` AS 'Operador', 
    `tipo_tec`.`tecnologia` AS 'Tecnologia', 
    `sitio`.`ancho_banda` AS 'Ancho Banda(Mb/s)', 
    `sitio`.`fecha_inst` AS 'Fecha Instalacion', 
    `sitio`.`cod_sace` AS 'Cod SACE', 
    `sitio`.`cod_cnt` AS 'Cod CONATEL'
FROM ((((((((`sitio`
 INNER JOIN `tipo_tec_sitio`
 ON `sitio`.`id_unico_sitio` = `tipo_tec_sitio`.`id_unico_sitio`)
 INNER JOIN `tipo_tec`
 ON `tipo_tec_sitio`.`id_tipo_tec` = `tipo_tec`.`id_tipo_tec`)
 INNER JOIN `administracion`
 ON `sitio`.`id_administracion` = `administracion`.`id_administracion`)
 INNER JOIN `estatus_finalizado`
 ON `sitio`.`id_estatus_finalizado` = `estatus_finalizado`.`id_estatus_finalizado`)
 INNER JOIN `departamentos`
 ON `sitio`.`id_departamento` = `departamentos`.`id_departamento`)
 INNER JOIN `municipios`
 ON `sitio`.`id_municipio` = `municipios`.`id_municipio`)
 INNER JOIN `sitios_has_operador`
 ON `sitio`.`id_unico_sitio` = `sitios_has_operador`.`id_unico_sitio`)
 INNER JOIN `operador`
 ON `sitios_has_operador`.`id_operador` = `operador`.`id_operador`)
```

The problem is that with that query I'm *only* getting the first 2 rows when on the database there are *five* rows.

Is there something wrong or something that limits the number of rows returned from the database on that query?

Comment: Maybe its because of `INNER JOIN`. Did you try `LEFT JOIN'

Comment: @JonesJoseph   thank's a lot!   It solved almost everything but some specific fields are still not showing up, at least the 5 rows are being returned.
I guess i have to keep playing with the joins until i get it working, thank's a lot man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `INNER JOIN` for all the tables, are you sure you have all five rows inside all the tables ? if one of the table only contains two rows, then at the end it will only show two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your INNER JOIN condition matches all the five rows in the table you need.